# Sum of consecutive cubes

Tags: nt.number-theory, polynomials, elliptic-curves, algebraic-curves, diophantine-equations

I'm investigating when the sum of $n$ consecutive cubes equals a cube, i.e., for which $n$ does

$$\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} (k+i)^3 = k^3 + (k+1)^3 + \cdots + (k+n-1)^3 = Y^3 $$

have nontrivial solutions $(k,Y)$ for $k, Y \in \mathbb{N} $. I have found (using programs) that if this equation has non-trivial solutions, n is not squarefree (for $n > 3$). Now I'm trying to prove that $n > 3$ cannot be squarefree. Here is a [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/v1snspj6ysq82g6/MathCubes_.pdf?dl=0) to my proof and what I've done so far but I've reached a wall. I have three equations that I believe contradict each other (I am almost certain they contradict each other). I just can't see how they contradict each other and I might need a new set of eyes to look at it. The three equations are given in the link but, if you like, I've put them below. I'm trying to show the following:

For natural numbers $ x, y, k, d \in \mathbb{N} $ and $ d > 1,$

1. $ d^2y = 2k + dx - 1 $
2. $ xy(d^4y^2+d^2x^2-1) = cube $
3. $ x {\space} | {\space} k(k-1) $

cannot all be true. Please let me know if you have any questions or suggestions for me! Thanks in advance!

Comment: Maybe it would be easier to consider $\left(\frac{b(b+1)}{2}\right)^{2} - \left(\frac{a(a+1)}{2}\right)^{2}.$

Comment: I've tried this. Unfortunately, you get back to the same equation I have...

Comment: In case anyone was wondering, Derek has already recorded this sequence in the OEIS.  http://oeis.org/A240970

Comment: Derek, does your system of three equations have any known solutions if some of the variables are allowed to be rational numbers rather than integers?

Comment: There is some discussion at https://www.mathpages.com/home/kmath147.htm

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Found some bigger numbers:
{n,k} as you call them:
{4913 , 11368}
{6591 , 305}
{6859 , 18171}
{8000 , 22534}
{10648 , 33558}
{12167 , 40381}
{13923 , 3010}
{14161 , 1624}
{25201 , 46690}
{33124 , 18551}
{63001 , 11170}
{48841 , 967190}
{277729 , 711785}
Most 'n' are squares, but a strange ones are 6591, 13923 and 25201

pipo

Comment: Forgot to mention, but it seems that 25201 is squarefree. pipo

Comment: $25201=11\times29\times79$.

Comment: I've confirmed pipo's example (Y = 1764070), so this answers Derek's question.  Perhaps Derek (or someone else) can say what solution to Derek's system of three equations pipo's example corresponds to.

Comment: @TimothyChow : I believe this corresponds to a solution $x=2291$, $y=980$, $d=11$, and $k=46690$.

Comment: @pipo Thanks! 6591 and 13923 are fine (both aren't squarefree) but yes it seems 25201 breaks it. And Thanks Timothy, Vladimir and Gerry, too. A little bummed...but thanks! At least I wasn't missing anything.

Comment: @pipo how did you find these? It seems {48841, 967190} and {277729, 711785} are incorrect.

Answer (score 11):

The question was explored on sci.net 20 years ago ; see [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20150106144342/http://www.math.niu.edu:80/%7Erusin/known-math/97/cube.sum). To summarize what was said then (the answer by Dave Rusin) : We have identified several types of solutions:

1. The trivial solutions --  $m=(1-k)/2$ (so $N=0$) for odd  $k$, and $m=-k/2$ or $-k/2+1$ for even  $k$
2. The torsion solutions -- $m=(u^3-2u^2-4u-4)(u-1)/6$  when $k=u^3$
3. Other elements in the subgroup generated by 1. and 2. (Conjecturally only $k=4$, $m=11$)
4. Other elements of rank-1 curves (None such? see Sect. VI)
5. Other generators of rank >1 curves (and linear combinations thereof) as for $k=3, 20, 25, 49, 99, 153, 288$

Comment: Thanks but I've looked at this link many times before. Rusin doesn't prove that n cannot be squarefree.